# MYSQL insert values with select

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to insert values like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO daily_food (number, weight, title, price) VALUES ('1', SELECT weight, title, price FROM food where title = '$add_food' LIMIT 1)";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

I have database with food which i'm selecting from. I would like to insert that number aswell but code is doing nothing. I'm new in sql so i can't figure out how the code should look.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `insert . . . select`, `values` is not necessary:

```
INSERT INTO daily_food (number, weight, title, price) 
    SELECT 1, weight, title, price
    FROM food 
    WHERE title = '$add_food'
    LIMIT 1;
```

Im assuming that `number` is, indeed, a number, so quotes are not needed.

In addition, you should be passing in `$add_food` as a parameter, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO daily_food (number, weight, title, price) 
    SELECT 1, weight, title, price
    FROM food 
    WHERE title = ?
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Not to the syntax error the OP is getting.  But, it is important for other reasons.

Comment: There is that, the number is not in the food database. I would like to give it strictly to the data in daily_food database.

Comment: @JakubKříž . . . You probably want an auto-increment column in `daily_food` (and a name such as `daily_food_id` instead of `number`).  That said, it doesn't have to be in `food` because this query returns it as a constant.